# Trying to swap a controller using an event listener with Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I've been reading through the internals chapter in the Symfony2 docs and it says if I add a listener to the kernel.controller event I can swap the controller that gets run, I've got something that works a bit like this:

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)    
{
    $controller = $event->getController();

    $replacementControllerName = .... //Some logic to work out the name of the new controller
    $replacementController = ?? //Not sure what goes here

    $event->setController($replacementController);
}
```

The bit I'm unsure if is once I've worked out the name of the replacement controller, how do I get an instance of it that I can pass to setController?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set your controller to any **callable**, which means something like

- A static method `array('class', 'method')`
- An instance method `array($instance, 'method')`
- An anonymous function `function() { ... }`
- A regular global function `'function'`;
- An instance of a class implementing the [`__invoke()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke) method `new MyClassImplementingInvoke()`
- The special syntax `'class::method'` which forces the [`ControllerResolver`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php) to create a new instance of `class` (calling the constructor without any argument) and returning a callable `array($instanceOfClass, 'method')`

**EDIT:**

I looked up the wrong `ControllerResolver`. When running Symfony in a standard setup it'll use the [`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php) (and not the [`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php)). So the controller name will be handled a little bit different to what I wrote above.

The following example sums up all the possible options you have when setting your controller.

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)    
{
    $controller = $event->getController();
    // call method in Controller class in YourBundle
    $replacementController = 'YourBundle:Controller:method';
    // call method in service (which is a service registered in the DIC)
    $replacementController = 'service:method';
    // call method on an instance of Class (created by calling the constructor without any argument)
    $replacementController = 'Class::method';
    // call method on Class statically (static method)
    $replacementController = array('Class', 'method');
    // call method on $controller
    $controller            = new YourController(1, 2, 3);
    $replacementController = array($controller, 'method');
    // call __invoke on $controller
    $replacementController = new YourController(1, 2, 3);
    $event->setController($replacementController);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm still having trouble getting something working, which of those options is the best way to get a controller setup so it will work as if Symfony had created it?

Comment: Sorry I might be being stupid but I'm still not sure how to make this work, can you post some example code? I'm a bit confused because I thought class::method always referred to a static method so I can't see how they would trigger ControllerResolver to do anything.

Comment: I added some example. Please take a look into the `createController()` method in both `ControllerResolver` classes and the `getController()` method in `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver`to get a feeling on how this works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think this is working now. I had to add a getContainer() method to my controller so I could add the container to the new controller but it seems to be working now.

Comment: Does that method (the 'bundle:controller:method') still work in the latest 2.0.10 version? I can't get it to work: see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256386/symfony2-set-controller-in-the-kernelcontrollerevent-using-bundlecontrolleract)

Comment: Why is this not officially documented?

Comment: It is - at least somehow: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-controller-event

Comment: If this doesn't work for anyone, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491505/trying-to-swap-a-controller-using-an-event-listener-with-symfony2