# Symfony2 Set Controller in the kernelControllerEvent using bundle:controller:action notation

Tags: symfony

I am trying to do something like the following question:

[Trying to swap a controller using an event listener with Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491505/trying-to-swap-a-controller-using-an-event-listener-with-symfony2)

However, when I use the code (as recommended in the answer):

```
$event->setController('MyMainBundle:Manage:show');
```

I just get an error:

```
LogicException: The controller must be a callable (MyMainBundle:Manage:show given).
```

Is there a way to use that Bundle:Controller:Method syntax in setController?  Or maybe some other method I can call to resolve that to a "callable"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should give to `$event->setController` is a callable.
What you give a string representing the logical path to a callable.

You can resolve this string using symfony's ControllerResolver.

You have to inject the `controller_resolver` service in your listener, and then use it like this:

```
$request = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request();
$request->attributes->set('_controller', 'MyMainBundle:Manage:show'));
$event->setController($this->resolver->getController($request));
```

But you are clearly doing the framework's job here.

Comment: When you say I'm doing the framework's job here, are you recommending against this method?  Is there a better way you would recommend?

Comment: Also, do I want `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver` or `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver`?

Comment: Also, marking as correct for now since it worked, but I am curious about the questions I asked.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend you to directly calculate the callable instead of asking the `controller_resolver`. But it depends what you want to do :) For example, if you already know what controller you want, instead of using bundle notation (eg: `MyMainBundle:Manage:show`), you could directly do `$this->setController(array(new MyMainBundle\Controller\Manage, 'show' ));`

Comment: Concerning your first question, the `controller_resolver` service is an instance of `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver`. It's the only one capable of parsing `Bundle:Controller:action` syntax.